# Material-UI: How can I change TablePagination caption that tells how many rows shown?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I want to change the string of the word "of" to another word, I tried to do so through `node_modules` but it didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
<TableFooter>
  <TableRow>
    <TablePagination
      rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25, { label: "All", value: -1 }]}
      count={props.generalIndicatorDataItem.length}
      rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
      page={page}
      labelRowsPerPage="عدد السلع فى الصفحة"
      onChangePage={handleChangePage}
      onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
      ActionsComponent={TablePaginationActions}
    />
  </TableRow>
</TableFooter>
```

And here is a screenshot of what I have:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`labelDisplayedRows`](https://material-ui.com/api/table-pagination/) props is a callback with the following signature:

```
({ from, to, count }) => string
```

This is how you use it correctly:

```
labelDisplayedRows={({ from, to, count }) =>
  `${from}-${to} OF ${count !== -1 ? count : `MORE THAN ${to}`}`}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67297785/material-ui-how-can-i-change-tablepagination-caption-that-tells-how-many-rows-s]

Comment: i tried it but it didn't effect the text , i already used this props as the code above  {labelRowsPerPage="عدد السلع فى الصفحة"}

Comment: @mostafaelbanna You are assigning `labelRowsPerPage` to a string `"عدد السلع فى الصفحة"` while the `labelRowsPerPage` only accepts callback. Did you copy the example in the my code snippet to make sure it works?

Comment: yes, i already tried to comment my value  and copied the code above <TablePagination
              
              labelRowsPerPage={({ from, to, count }) =>
                `${from}-${to} من ${count !== -1 ? count : `أكثر من  ${to}`}`
              }
              // labelRowsPerPage="عدد السلع فى الصفحة"
            
             
            />

Comment: @mostafaelbanna Sorry, my bad. It's `labelDisplayedRows`, not `labelRowsPerPage`

Comment: oh, finally its working... Thanks for your efforts